# ASP.NET MVC Why doesn't my routing work after publish?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, publishing

i've got the following routeMaps setup for my website. Running and debugging locally works perfectly. I can publish the website to my server (www) but only the root page works (http://www.domain.com). As soon as I specify a controller (http://www.domain.com/Project) it stops working...

What am i doing wrong?

**Global.asax.vb**

```
' Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
' visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394802

Public Class MvcApplication
Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

    ' MapRoute takes the following parameters, in order:
    ' (1) Route name
    ' (2) URL with parameters
    ' (3) Parameter defaults

    routes.MapRoute("ProjectsByCategory", "Project/Category/{id}", _
                    New With {.controller = "Project", .action = "ListByCategory", .id = ""}, _
                    New With {.id = "^[0-9]+"})


    routes.MapRoute( _
        "Default", _
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
        New With {.controller = "Project", .action = "Index", .id = ""} _
    )

End Sub

Sub Application_Start()
    Common.LoadEntitySpacesFactory()
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is your publishing server config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you deploying to an IIS6 server? If so there are some steps you need to take [detailed here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx). If not, can you explain the error a little more - what exactly does "it stops working..." mean?

Comment: It sounds like this is exactly what's happening.  IIS6 doesn't support the URL rewriting-ish features that MVC routing needs.  The workaround is pretty simple, though.

Comment: True, I needed to add Wildcard mapping to aspnet_isapi.dll in the application configuration. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying to IIS5? If so follow [this](http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2008/11/deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-on-windows-xp-iis.html).